# How to get server status using multi-threads periodically

Tags: java, multithreading, server, client, callable

The below code works fine and it connects to a given server (host, port) and gets the connection status.

What it does is:

1. PollService implements the Callable interface and connects to a server(host, port) then it returns the status.
2. Since this should happen periodically, it iterates the Hashmap entries in a while(true) loop infinitely.

The problem: On the server-side, I see it takes 2 or 3 seconds to reach the thread and if I use Runnable with periodic implementation it connects within 1 sec. Looks like iterating the Hashmap infinitely is a slow approach.

However, I can not use Runnable as it doesn't return the status of the connection which I need later to use.

Below is the ServiceMonitor class (client) which connects to the server.

```
package org.example;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ServicesMonitor {
  private ExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = null;
  private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ServicesMonitor.class.getName());
  private final Map<ServiceType, List<ClientMonitorService>> clientMonitorServicesMap = new HashMap<>();

  public void registerInterest(ClientMonitorService clientMonitorService) {
    clientMonitorServicesMap.computeIfAbsent(clientMonitorService.getServiceToMonitor().getServiceType(), v -> new ArrayList<>()).add(clientMonitorService);
  }

  public Map<ServiceType, List<ClientMonitorService>> getClineMonitorService() {
    return clientMonitorServicesMap;
  }

  public void poll(){
    //Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).st
  }
  public void pollServices() {
    scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(clientMonitorServicesMap.size());
    try {

      while (true) {
        clientMonitorServicesMap.forEach((k, v) -> {
          Future<Boolean> val = scheduledExecutorService.submit(new PollService(k));
          try {
            boolean result = val.get();
            System.out.println("service " + k.getHost() + ":" + k.getPort() + "status is " + result);
            if (result) {
              List<ClientMonitorService> list = v.stream().filter(a -> LocalDateTime.now().getSecond() % a.getServiceToMonitor().getFreqSec() == 0)
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
              list.stream().forEach(a -> System.out.println(a.getClientId()));
            }

          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }

        });
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage());
    } finally {
      scheduledExecutorService.shutdown();
    }
  }
}
```

- How to improve the performance of this code by reducing the time it takes to connect to the server?
- How to improve this code?

Comment: you're iterating the list twice. try removing the collector and streaming once.

Comment: The test was done without the collector that uses the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after using the get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS); I started to see improvement on the server side as well (Reaching the threads less than 1 second) since we are not waiting more than 1 second on the client side.

```
while (true) {
    clientMonitorServicesMap.forEach((k, v) -> {
      Future<Boolean> val = scheduledExecutorService.submit(new PollService(k));
      try {
        boolean result = val.get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println("service " + k.getHost() + ":" + k.getPort() + "status is " + result);
        if (result) {
          List<ClientMonitorService> list = v.stream()
                  //.filter(a -> LocalDateTime.now().getSecond() % a.getServiceToMonitor().getFreqSec() == 0)
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
          list.stream().forEach(a -> System.out.println(a.getClientId()));
        }

      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       logger.log(Level.WARNING,"Interrupted -> " + k.getHost()+":"+k.getPort());
      } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        logger.log(Level.INFO,"ExecutionException exception -> "+ k.getHost()+":"+k.getPort());
      } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        logger.log(Level.INFO,"TimeoutException exception -> "+ k.getHost()+":"+k.getPort());
      }

    });
  }
```